# How to access to AVS full features on iOS Swift App with HTTP2 integration

Tags: ios, alexa-skills-kit, avs

Im developing an iOS Swift mobile App with Alexa AVS HTTP2 integration, basically I added a record button to access to Alexa avs. The integration works well so far, Alexa responds most of the questions. But when I ask something like "Alexa turn on my tv" Alexa responds "that feature is only supported by Alexa built in devices" Since for my app is important to Alexa turn on and off devices I would like to test this feature. So reading the amazon documentation I guess I need a certification to access to avs full features (https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/devices/connected-devices/business-resources/works-with-alexa).
Reading the documentation for certification, everithing just points to certificate a device, but in my case it is a mobile app, im confused with with this.

So Im I right? I need to certificate my iOS app while developing to access and test full features?
If someone gone through this, do you know how much is the fee cost for testing and certifying a product like a mobile app?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is right, you need to certificate your app. If you would like access to a particular AVS feature, you may be interested in hiring a Systems Integrator (SI). Systems Integrators offer hardware modules, software, and services to help you easily integrate Alexa into connected products. For more information and a list of available SIs for hire, please visit the below resource:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/solution-providers/systems-integrators

Additionally, if you would like help with manufacturing an end device, you may be interested in hiring an Original Design Manufacturer (ODM). ODMs provide custom hardware and software design, development, certification, and manufacturing. For more information and a list of available ODMs for hire, please visit the below resource:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/solution-providers/odm-solutions

I hope this helps. If you need any additional support, please feel free to reach back out. Thank you for your interest in Alexa!